# Push an array inside a array and after update array and save to database - angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to push an array comment in to cabin.comments array and after UPDATE of the cabin array with the new comment in it when the user submits a comment using the onSubmit() and update the cabin with the updateCabin.
In the console when running "ng serve --open" I am getting an error:

error TS1128: Declaration or statement expect

I am using a JSON database in the main folder.
I am really new to angular and I am lost.

This is my component

```
            import { Location } from '@angular/common';
    import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Params, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


    import { Comment } from '../shared/comment';
    import { Cabin } from '../shared/cabin';
    import { CabinService } from '../services/cabin.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-cabin-detail',
      templateUrl: './cabin-detail.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./cabin-detail.component.css']
    })
    export class CabinDetailComponent implements OnInit {
       cabin: Cabin;
       cabins: Cabin[];
      comment: Comment;
      commentForm: FormGroup;
      errMess: string;


      formErrors = {
        'author' : '',
        'rating' : '',
        'comment' : ''
      };

      validationMessages = {
        'author' : {
          'required' : 'Name is required',
          'minlength' : 'Name must be at least 2 characters long',
          'maxlength' : 'Name cannot be more that 25 characters long'
        }
      };


      constructor(
        private cabinService: CabinService,
         private fb: FormBuilder,
        private location: Location,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        @Inject("BaseURL") private BaseURL
      ) {
        this.createForm();
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getCabin();
        this.getCabins();


      }

      getCabin(): void {
        const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.cabinService.getCabin(id)
          .subscribe(cabin => this.cabin = cabin);
      }


      getCabins(): void {
        this.cabinService.getCabins()
        .subscribe(cabins => this.cabins = cabins);
      }

    /* addComment(description: string): void {
        description = description.trim();
        if (!description) { return; }
        this.cabinService.addCabin({ description } as Cabin)
          .subscribe(cabin => {
            this.cabins.push(cabin);
          });
      }
     */
     /* delete(cabin: Cabin): void {
        this.cabins = this.cabins.filter(h => h !== cabin);
        this.cabinService.deleteCabin(cabin).subscribe();
      }
      */

        createForm() {
        this.commentForm = this.fb.group({
          author: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2) ] ],
          rating: 5,
          comment: ['', [ Validators.required ] ],
        });

        this.commentForm.valueChanges
          .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));

        this.onValueChanged(); // (re)set form validation messages
      }

        onValueChanged(commentFormData?: any) {
        if (!this.commentForm) {
          return;
        }
        const form = this.commentForm;
        for (const field in this.formErrors) {
          this.formErrors[field] = '';
          const control = form.get(field);
          if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
            const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
            for (const key in control.errors) {
              this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
            }
          }
        }

        if (this.commentForm.valid) {
          this.comment = this.commentForm.value;
        } else {
          this.comment = undefined;
        }
      }

      onSubmit(cabinId) {
        const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        console.log(cabinId)

        this.cabin.comments.push(this.comment);
        this.cabinService.updatePosts(cabinId);

        this.commentForm.reset({
            author: '',
            rating: 5,
            comment: ''
        });
      }


    }
```

My cabinService

```
            import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

    import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
    import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

    import { Cabin } from '../shared/cabin';
    import { MessageService } from './message.service';



    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class CabinService {

      private cabinsUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/cabins';  // URL to web api

      constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private messageService: MessageService) { }

      /** GET cabins from the server */
      getCabins(): Observable<Cabin[]> {
        return this.http.get<Cabin[]>(this.cabinsUrl)
          .pipe(
            tap(cabins => this.log('fetched cabins')),
            catchError(this.handleError('getCabins', []))
          );
      }

      getFeaturedCabin(): Observable<Cabin[]> {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3000/cabins?featured=true';
        return this.http.get<Cabin[]>(url).pipe(
          tap(_ => this.log('o')),
          catchError(this.handleError<Cabin[]>(`getFeaturedCabin`))
        );
      }
      /** GET cabin by id. Return `undefined` when id not found */
      getCabinNo404<Data>(id: number): Observable<Cabin> {
        const url = `${this.cabinsUrl}/?id=${id}`;
        return this.http.get<Cabin[]>(url)
          .pipe(
            map(cabins => cabins[0]), // returns a {0|1} element array
            tap(h => {
              const outcome = h ? `fetched` : `did not find`;
              this.log(`${outcome} cabin id=${id}`);
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError<Cabin>(`getCabin id=${id}`))
          );
      }

      /** GET cabin by id. Will 404 if id not found */
      getCabin(id: number): Observable<Cabin> {
        const url = `${this.cabinsUrl}/${id}`;
        return this.http.get<Cabin>(url).pipe(
          tap(_ => this.log(`fetched cabin id=${id}`)),
          catchError(this.handleError<Cabin>(`getCabin id=${id}`))
        );
      }

          updatePosts(id) {
        const comment:Comment= {   author: '',
        rating: '',
        comment: '',
        date: '' };
        return this.http.get<Cabin>('http://localhost:3000/cabins/' + id).pipe(
          map(cabin => {
            console.log(cabin);


            return {
              description: cabin.description,
              featured: cabin.featured,
              comments: cabin.comments

            };


          })
        ).subscribe(updatedEntries => {
          console.log(updatedEntries);

          updatedEntries.comments.push(data);
          return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/cabins/' + id, updatedEntries);

        });

      }



      /*



      /**
       * Handle Http operation that failed.
       * Let the app continue.
       * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
       * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
       */
      private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
        return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

          // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
          console.error(error); // log to console instead

          // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
          this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

          // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
          return of(result as T);
        };
      }

      /** Log a CabinService message with the MessageService */
      private log(message: string) {
        this.messageService.add(`CabinService: ${message}`);
      }

    }
```

My JSON database

```
      "cabins": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "description": "Tucked away on the hillside among lush gardens of banana & citrus trees",
          "featured": "true",
          "comments": [
            {
              "rating": 5,
              "comment": "Beautiful place!",
              "author": "John Gomez",
              "date": "2018-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
              "rating": 4,
              "comment": "Amazing!",
              "author": "Paul Villar",
              "date": "2017-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Comment: in your subscribe, if you take out the `this.cacin = cabin` and add a `console.log(cabin)`, do you get the full cabin object or just the comments?

Comment: I get the full cabin

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue is with the put method itself, you need to put back the whole object.. what I like to do is get the object first then add the data and push it all back as it was if you use mongoose for example you can update just the child schema of a schema, but it depends on the db engine..

```js
updatePosts(){
 const data={"last": "test2"};

 return this.http.get<{post: Posts}>('http://localhost:3000/posts/5').pipe(
  map(post=>{
    console.log(post);


     return{
           description: cabin.description,
           featured: cabin.featured,
           comments: cabin.comments

         };


     })
    ).subscribe(updatedEntries=>{
      updatedEntries.cabin.comments.push(data);
      return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/cabins/'+id, updatedEntries);



});
```